# how to use Authenticator with suspend api function? Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, kotlin-coroutines

I am building client:

```
OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .authenticator(object : Authenticator {
        override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
            val request = AppPreferences.refreshToken?.let {
                api.refreshTokenC(it).execute()
            }
            
         ...
        })
```

and for this I use usual fun which returns Call :

```
@POST("Accounts/refresh")
fun refreshTokenC(@Query("refreshToken") refreshToken: String): Call<TokenResponse>
```

But how can use it with suspend function?:

```
    @POST("Accounts/refresh")
suspend fun refreshToken(@Query("refreshToken") refreshToken: String): Response<TokenResponse>
```

Answer (score 3):

- `fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response)` is not suspend function, we cannot invoke suspend function from it.
- Can use `runBlocking`:

> Runs a new coroutine and blocks the current thread interruptibly until its completion. This function should not be used from a coroutine. It is designed to bridge regular blocking code to libraries that are written in suspending style, to be used in main functions and in tests.

- `fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response)` is being called on a background thread, we can use `runBlocking` safely.

```kotlin
val request = AppPreferences.refreshToken?.let { token ->
    runBlocking { api.refreshToken(token) }
}
```

*Similar code: [AuthInterceptor.kt](https://github.com/hoc081098/Edoctor-MVI-Arrow-RxKotlin-Coroutines-Flow/blob/54606d62847d8f313a04a96790d2cbc4523efaa3/app/src/main/java/com/doancnpm/edoctor/data/remote/interceptor/AuthInterceptor.kt#L36)*

Comment: This is not a good solution with kotlin coroutines, you should bridge to the async API instead.

Comment: `authenticate ` is not suspend function

Comment: If you edit your post slightly, I'll change my vote.

Comment: how about the `Unconfined` scope?

Comment: @mochadwi it's fine to use `Unconfined`